# iOS MKMapViewDelegate - Getting UserLocation the second time

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

I create a MKMapView and associate a MKMapViewDelegate with it.

The MKMapViewDelegate gets notified correctly that DidUpdateUserLocation and other life cycle events occurred.

When I create another MKMapView later on in the app, the MKMapViewDelegate doesn't receive any notifications about MapLoaded or the like. Just the constructor is fired.

How do I get a new map instance the 2nd time to update the MKMapViewDelegate with lifecycle events?

Comment: Yes, but a new one. I found if I use the RegionDidChange event, that will work though.

Comment: it sounds kinda odd, shouldn't happen. How are you creating both mapviews.. could you post some example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .NET for iPhones (MonoTouch)

In the Map Delegate handle this event ONCE only, it gets fired a lot. This way you never need to worry about how the map caches.

```
    public override void RegionChanged (MKMapView mapView, bool animated)
    {
        if (!hasSetupMapBoolean)
        {
            localCopymap = mapView;
            DoYourSetupMap ();
        }
    }
```